# WPF insert non english text into listview

Tags: wpf, binding

SO i have simple `ListView` with binding:

**View model:**

```
ObservableCollection<ClipboardItem> Clipboards;
```

**ListView:**

```
    <ListView Name="ListViewUsers"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Clipboards}"/>
<ListView.View>
                            <GridView >
                                <GridViewColumn>
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}"
                                                               Foreground="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}"
                                                               Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

And all my non english text (`Hebrew`) is display `as ???`

Any suggestions how to fix it ?

```
Edit
```

I added my `ClipboardItem` class:

```
public class ClipboardItem
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
```

I also add my `Clipboard` event:

```
private void ClipboardMonitor_OnClipboardContentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string clipboardText = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text);
            viewModel.Clipboards.Add(new ClipboardItem { Text = clipboardText });
        }
```

**ClipboardMonitor**:

```
public sealed class ClipboardMonitor : IDisposable
    {
        private static class NativeMethods
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Places the given window in the system-maintained clipboard format listener list.
            /// </summary>
            [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            public static extern bool AddClipboardFormatListener(IntPtr hwnd);

            /// <summary>
            /// Removes the given window from the system-maintained clipboard format listener list.
            /// </summary>
            [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            public static extern bool RemoveClipboardFormatListener(IntPtr hwnd);

            /// <summary>
            /// Sent when the contents of the clipboard have changed.
            /// </summary>
            public const int WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE = 0x031D;

            /// <summary>
            /// To find message-only windows, specify HWND_MESSAGE in the hwndParent parameter of the FindWindowEx function.
            /// </summary>
            public static IntPtr HWND_MESSAGE = new IntPtr(-3);
        }

        private HwndSource hwndSource = new HwndSource(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null, NativeMethods.HWND_MESSAGE);

        public ClipboardMonitor()
        {
            hwndSource.AddHook(WndProc);
            NativeMethods.AddClipboardFormatListener(hwndSource.Handle);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            NativeMethods.RemoveClipboardFormatListener(hwndSource.Handle);
            hwndSource.RemoveHook(WndProc);
            hwndSource.Dispose();
        }

        private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
        {
            if (msg == NativeMethods.WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE)
            {
                OnClipboardContentChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }

            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Occurs when the clipboard content changes.
        /// </summary>
        public event EventHandler OnClipboardContentChanged;
    }
```

**edit**

```
private ClipboardMonitor clipboardMonitor;

public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitiateClipboardMonitor();
        }

private void InitiateClipboardMonitor()
        {
            clipboardMonitor = new ClipboardMonitor();
            clipboardMonitor.OnClipboardContentChanged += ClipboardMonitor_OnClipboardContentChanged;
        }
```

Comment: I copied text by using google translate English to Hebrew by making the list Clipboards of ObservableCollection of String Type. The text displayed correctly. Could you please provide ClipboardItem class or any functionality to put it in the ClipboardItem object.

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: the hebrew text is displayed correctly in listbox. Is there any function/ method which adds the text in the class object. I guess that is causing the issue. Also could you  remove the ending tag ItemsSource="{Binding Clipboards}"/>

Comment: i saw that sometimes when i copy text from webpage this display ???? appears and sometimes not, what could cause this strange behavior ?

Comment: I also add my Clipboard event, please see my update

Comment: it may be the same text/character that is causing the issue ? what text you are getting "???"

Comment: Only Hebrew, but as i mentioned this not cause all the time

Comment: I also add my ClipboardMonitor class, this class listening for the clipboard text, maybe this cause this issue ? (i also notice that every clipboard copy lead to the same event 3 times)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the TextDataFormat.Text to TextDataFormat.UnicodeText

```
        private void ClipboardMonitor_OnClipboardContentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string clipboardText = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.UnicodeText);
        Clipboards.Add(new ClipboardItem { Text = clipboardText });
    }
```

Comment: @user979033 the issue was reproduced and after changing this to UniCodeText it is working for me. Checkout this, let me know if there is anymore case.

Comment: Yes this looks fine now, i only cannot figure why every clipboard copy lead to the same event 3 times

Comment: @user979033 ClipboardMonitor_OnClipboardContentChanged is only called once. you might have pointed it more than once i guess using delegate

Comment: Yes, but still 3 time same event, i moved all the code and my ClipboardMonitor_OnClipboardContentChanged function is now empty and still 3 times

Comment: @user979033 could you also show how ClipboardMonitor_OnClipboardContentChanged event is subscribed ? I have put it in Window's class constructor

Comment: @user979033 I also coded the same in Windows 10. It is working fine.